# Takes a very long time to log in to gnome 3.18.4 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 via update from 14.04. I'm using gnome-shell 3.18.4.
When I want to log to my gnome shell session the login is very slow, it takes more than 1 minute where the the only thing
displayed is the wallpaper and then the gnome-shell session appears (the boot sequence works fine, although I don't see the Ubuntu Icon that should be displayed during this sequence after Grub, it is quick, the problem is after the login screen).
Here are a few facts:

- It works perfectly when login to Unity
- After login to unity and ending the unity session it works perfectly when I login to the gnome session.
- I removed all gnome extensions and this does not change the problem
- I removed .gconf .local and .config and this does not change anything
- Here is the .xsession-errors:

openConnection: connect: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cannot connect to brltty at :0

- I deleted .Xauthority and .ICEauthorithy but this did not solve the problem
- I looked on the web but I have serious difficulties to understand what people say about this type of problem and what to do.

My computer is an HP EliteBook 840.
Any help would be welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Solved, this was a problem with alsa.

Here is what I did.

> dmesg | less

gave me a message "error"

> snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Disabling via vga_switcheroo

that I could locate to happen just before login thanks to the timing.
I looked on this webpage: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1460933#p1460933

I thus created a file

> /etc/modprobe.d/my-alsa.conf

in which I put the only line

> options snd-hda-intel enable=0,1,0

Now the problem has disappeared. That being said the sound via displayport does not work anymore but this is a minor annoyance.